# FactoryGirl create_list pass in multiple values

Tags: ruby, factory-bot

If I have this factory:

```
factory :product, class: Product do
  name        { Faker::Commerce.product_name }
  description { Faker::Lorem.paragraph }
  price       { Faker::Number.number(3) }
end
```

I can use `create_list` to create 2 products like this:

```
FactoryGirl.create_list(:product, 2)
```

but I want to pass in defaults to both my products, I would suppose something theoretically like this?:

```
prods = [{:name => "Product 1"},{:name => "Product 2"}]
FactoryGirl.create_list(:product, prods.count, prods)
```

I have searched for a while and cannot find the answer to this, is it possible using an elegant solution like `create_list`?

The reason I would like this solution is because `:product` is one of many child associations to a parent model. I would like a configurable way that I could generate the parent model factory through a single `FactoryGirl.create` command and pass in all the values I would like for child associations (through the use of FactoryGirl's traits and ignore blocks). I hope that makes sense. I could show a bunch of code here but I believe this provides enough context?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can generate the list yourself:

```
data = [{:name => "Product 1"},{:name => "Product 2"}]
products = data.map { |p| FactoryGirl.create(:product, p) }
```

Which should leave you with an array of products.

Answer (score 7):

Since [v5.2.0](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/releases/tag/v5.2.0) you can do this:

```
twenty_somethings = create_list(:user, 10) do |user, i|
  user.date_of_birth = (20 + i).years.ago
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this thread looking for a similar solution. If you are actually just wanting to sequence the name like your example, you can use `sequence` in the factory and then `create_list` -- which I found could be used as a trait as well. My need was to increment a timestamp when creating a list of records:

```
trait :sequentially_longer_ago do
  sequence(:created_at) { |n| n.days.ago }
end
```

and then:

```
create_list(:my_record, 123, :sequentially_longer_ago, foo: 'bar')
```

So in your case, it might be:

```
trait :sequence_product_name do
  sequence(:name) { |n| "Product #{n + 1}" }
end
```

and then:

```
create_list(:product, 123, :sequence_product_name, foo: 'bar')
```